# ngAnimate doesn't work when modify condition too fast in code

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate

I am working on a search page. If no result was returned form server, the no result message box will appear, and if the user still search for that word again, I want the fade out and fade in effect for the message box for user to know the page worked for their search. Everything work fine for this case, since I hide the message box before send the search request to server.

But when I add some validation to the page, the fade out fade in effect doesn't work when I try to hide and show message box for invalid search criteria continuously. At fist I thought I was because I change message state too close in the code. But the problem seems to be different.

When I try to change message from no result to invalid, the effect happens.

It sounds complicated so here is the summary:

- Multiple no results messages -> works fine (did call to server)
- Multiple invalid search criteria -> doesn't work (no server call)
- From no results to invalid search criteria -> works fine (no server call and I don't know why the above doesn't work but this does)
- From invalid search criteria to no result -> works fine (no doubts because there is a server call)

I think this might have something to to with the built in $apply function in angular.

Here is the code

```
var showNoResult = function() {
    vm.showSearchResult = false;   //result table
    vm.showMsg2 = false;           //invalid
    vm.showMsg1 = true;            //no result
    vm.showMsg = true;             //message box
};     
var showInvalid = function() {            
    vm.showSearchResult = false;
    vm.showMsg1 = false;
    vm.showMsg2 = true;
    vm.showMsg = true;  
};      
var hideMsg = function() {
    vm.showMsg = false;
    vm.showMsg1 = false;
    vm.showMsg2 = false;
};
vm.sendData = function(page) {
    hideMsg();
    if(!isFormValid()) {               
        showInvalid();     //problem here
        return;
    }
    // call to server
    mapData(function(data) {                
        data.pagenum = page || 1;
        searchService.searchEmployee(data).then(function(response) {                    
            if (response.data[0] == 0) {
                showNoResult();
                return;
            }
            vm.users = response.data[1];
            vm.totalItem = response.data[0];
            vm.showSearchResult = true;
        });
    });
};
```

And this is the html:

```
<div id="message-box" class="panel panel-default ng-hide" ng-show="searchCtrl.showMsg">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <i class="fa fa-info" aria-hidden="true" id="no-result-icon"></i>
        <p id="no-result-text" ng-show="searchCtrl.showMsg1">   
            <b>{{ searchCtrl.msg.msg1.msg1_1}}</b>
            <br>                                        
            {{ searchCtrl.msg.msg1.msg1_2}}
        </p>
        <p id="invalid-form-text" ng-show="searchCtrl.showMsg2">
            {{ searchCtrl.msg.msg2 }}
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain better?

Comment: @developer033 which part do you want me to explain more?

Comment: Can you provide a plnkr to demonstrate better your situation?